# When to use setState() if you are already using bloc or provider or anything? or is a bad practice overall

Tags: flutter, setstate, state-management

So I heard a teacher saying he uses `setState` when the code is simple enough, which I thought was bad, because then why should I use any state management library? Is it just to split code?

I also though `setState` re-builds the whole screen in all instances but I discovered that this is not particularly correct? I thought I got the whole idea but I am a bit confused now..

My question here is when am I allowed to use `setState` if I'm using bloc, riverpod, or anything? Like, what are my limits?

Should I use `setState` with something like a navbar ? because NavBars rebuilds the whole screen in all cases and It's a lot easier and more readable if I just used `setState` with it

Comment: setState is for ephemeral state inside the widget.  state management is for state shared between widgets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to understand what kinds of state exist, and why state management libraries emerged. Flutter official docs and YouTube videos provide plenty of high-quality information on those topics. For instance, start with this [introductory video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqCMFXEmf3w&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIJyiwUPCou_OVTpRIn_8UMd&index=4).

In almost any application, there are two major types of state: app state (aka "global" or "app-wide" state) and ephemeral state (aka "local state"). The key difference between them is that the app state should be readily available for using (consuming) on any screen and in virtually any part of the application (eg. the app settings). In contrast, the ephemeral state usually only makes sense within a particular part of the app (eg. a boolean state of an expandable content block – collapsed or expanded). But in the end, this is your job, as a developer, to decide what in your app belongs to the app state vs ephemeral state. For instance, your app might need to know (on any screen and at any given moment) if the expandable block on the main screen is currently expanded or collapsed, because this knowledge somehow serves the app's business logic. In this case, the block's state would be a part of the app state.

So the Flutter's simplest state management mechanism `StatefulWidget` + `setState` is more suitable for the ephemeral state because it doesn't allow for easy sharing of the state between screens and other widgets (and while it's possible to pass the state as widgets' arguments deep down the tree, this approach is obviously cumbersome and error-prone). Usually, `setState` is more than enough to handle an ephemeral state.

As to the app state management, Flutter also provides a built-in mechanism for it called [InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) but it's pretty limited and not well-suited for a whole range of use cases. That's why app state management libraries (such as [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) or [Bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc)) emerged – they are more geared towards the app's global state management. Competing with each other and offering different approaches, they try to make the app's global state management as simple and convenient as possible for developers.

Answering you main question – in general, it's perfectly fine to use the Flutter's built-in `StatefulWidget`'s `setState` method alongside any app state management library (with rare exceptions probably), simply because these mechanisms have pretty different purposes and do not naturally conflict with each other. Moreover, most of the time you'll find yourself using a state management library alongside the `InheritedWidget` because many things in Flutter depend on it behind the scene (eg. `Theme.of(context)`), and this will not do any harm.

There is also an [excellent thesis](https://www.theseus.fi/bitstream/handle/10024/355086/Dmitrii_Slepnev.pdf) by Dmitrii Slepnev that compares the most popular State Management mechanisms and libraries for Flutter.

Comment: This pretty well explained, thanks a lot! But, in which use case should I use InheritedWidget along side a state management library. I thought s-m libraries are fine on their own as they serve the same purpose ?

Comment: You're welcome! There are no such cases – what I meant was that you'll be using at least Flutter's Theme object in almost any app, and that Theme object already uses the InheritedWidget mechanism under the hood anyway. Such ready-made InheritedWidget-s are everywhere in Flutter.